# How to use a countdown timer correctly in android

Tags: java, android, countdown

I have a return date(somewhere in near furture) stored within the application.

Now i need a find out current time of the android phone , then i can find out the amount of mins hours to countdown from . the below is what i have at the moment, when i create the below object i pass it `PinnedCountdownTimer pct = new PinnedCountdownTimer((getTimeToReturn().getTime()-System.currentTimeMillis()),1000,countdownTv);`

```
public class PinnedCountdownTimer extends CountDownTimer {

TextView tv;
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
Date resultdate ;
public PinnedCountdownTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval,TextView tv) {
    super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    this.tv = tv;
}

@Override
public void onFinish() {
    tv.setText("get back to your car!");
}

@Override
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    resultdate = new Date(millisUntilFinished);
    tv.setText("Left: " + sdf.format(resultdate) );
}
```

}

this does not work correctly.....do you guys have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html), you need to call pct.start() from what I'm reading. Otherwise, I'm not an Android developer, but there's also the [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) class which is in regular Java, and looks to be available in Android as well.